# Which is the best way to move data from exchange to another exchange for two differents RabbitMQ servers?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

the thing is I have two RabbitMQ cluster servers (prod and dev) and in the prod server I have an exchange where external applications push data, but they only can push the data in one server I need to move the data from that prod exchange to a dev exchange in another server to make some testing.  I was looking for a some extension that allows some kind of exchange binding inter servers, but I think that is not possible.  the only solution I can think of is a service/application that creates its own queue, makes binding to prod exchange and push the data from its queue to the dev exchange in another server without modify another application.  I want to know if this is the best way or if you know another more productive way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the Shovel Plugin. RabbitMQ Shovel, a core RabbitMQ plugin that unidirectionally moves messages from a source to a destination.

There is no requirement to run the shovel on the same broker (or cluster) as its source or destination, although that's the most typical approach; the shovel can run on an entirely separate node or cluster.

Checkout more here .. https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html

Here are some more links .. 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-dynamic.html
https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-static.html

Comment: It seems to work fine by making a shovel with exchanges with two differents brokers.  My mistake I thouhgt shovel tool only works with queues in the same broker.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the most appropriate use case for the shovel plugin is to transfer data between different clusters hosted in different geo-locations to support system with a secondary or a backup cluster that could be used in need